# Share PVs in Deployment for Redis ReJSON not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, devops, redisjson

#### Cluster information:

> Kubernetes version: Major:"1", Minor:"17"
>
> Cloud being used: **bare-metal**
>
> Installation method: **minikube** with kubectl
>
> Host OS: **Ubuntu 16.04**

#### Question:

I'm creating 3 replicas and gonna create JSON set in one of the pod. the data can accessed within that pod only. My question is how to access the same set and get it from another pod.

Here is YAML file :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: rejson
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 6379
  selector:
    app: rejson
---
apiVersion: apps/v1 # for versions before 1.9.0 use apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: rejson
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: rejson
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: rejson
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: redislabs/rejson
        args: ["--appendonly", "yes", "--save", "900", "1", "--save", "30", "2", "--loadmodule", "/usr/lib/redis/modules/rejson.so"] 
        name: rejson
        ports:
        - containerPort: 6379
          name: rejson
        volumeMounts:
        - name: rejson-persistent-storage
          mountPath: /data
      volumes:
      - name: rejson-persistent-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim: 
          claimName: rejson-pv-claim
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: rejson-pv-claim
  labels:
    app: rejson
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 20Gi
```

Comment: change `accessModes:` from     `- ReadWriteOnce` to `-ReadWriteMany`

Answer (score 1):

> The issue on your yaml is the access mode used, you should **change access mode to `ReadWriteMany`**

The access modes allowed are as below : [Refer Link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes)

> `ReadWriteOnce` – the volume can be mounted as read-write by a single node
>
> `ReadOnlyMany` – the volume can be mounted read-only by many nodes
>
> `ReadWriteMany` – the volume can be mounted as read-write by many nodes

Check this very basic example on how share file content between containers in a POD created via deployment using PV/PVC and is hared between replicas on scaling the deployment.

First **Create a persistent volume** refer below yaml example with hostPath configuration

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: my-pv-1
  labels:
    pv: my-pv-1
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  hostPath:
    path: /var/log/mypath

$ kubectl create -f pv.yaml
persistentvolume/my-pv-1 created
```

Second **create a persistent volume claim** using below yaml example

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: my-pvc-claim-1
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      pv: my-pv-1


$ kubectl create -f pvc.yaml
persistentvolumeclaim/my-pvc-claim-1 created
```

**Verify the pv and pvc STATUS is  set to BOUND**

```
$ kubectl get persistentvolume
NAME      CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS   CLAIM                  STORAGECLASS   REASON   AGE
my-pv-1   1Gi        RWX            Retain           Bound    default/my-pvc-claim-1                         62s

$ kubectl get persistentvolumeclaims
NAME             STATUS   VOLUME    CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
my-pvc-claim-1   Bound    my-pv-1   1Gi        RWX                           58
```

Third **consume the pvc in required both pods of a deployment** refer below example yaml where the volume is mounted on two pods busy1 and busy2 of a multi-pod deployment where file written in first container is readable on second.

multi-pod-deploy.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    app: multipod
  name: multipod
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: multipod
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: multipod
    spec:
      containers:
      - command:
        - sleep
        - "3600"
        image: busybox
        name: busy1
        volumeMounts:
        - name: vol
          mountPath: /var/log/mypath
      - command:
        - sleep
        - "3600"
        image: busybox
        name: busy2
        volumeMounts:
        - name: vol
          mountPath: /var/log/mypath
      volumes:
      - name: vol
        persistentVolumeClaim:
           claimName: my-pvc-claim-1


$ kubectl create -f multi-pod-deploy.yaml
deployment.apps/multipod created


$ kubectl get all
NAME                            READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/multipod-5758475c69-fkl57   2/2     Running   0          36s

NAME                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
service/kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1    <none>        443/TCP   37h

NAME                       READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/multipod   1/1     1            1           36s

NAME                                  DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/multipod-5758475c69   1         1         1       36s
```

**Test by connecting to container 1** and write to the file on mount-path.

```
$ kubectl exec -it multipod-5758475c69-fkl57 -c busy1 /bin/sh

/ # df -kh
Filesystem                Size      Used Available Use% Mounted on
overlay                  38.7G      4.1G     34.6G  11% /
tmpfs                    64.0M         0     64.0M   0% /dev
tmpfs                     7.8G         0      7.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/vda1                38.7G      4.1G     34.6G  11% /dev/termination-log
/dev/vda1                38.7G      4.1G     34.6G  11% /etc/resolv.conf
/dev/vda1                38.7G      4.1G     34.6G  11% /etc/hostname
/dev/vda1                38.7G      4.1G     34.6G  11% /etc/hosts
shm                      64.0M         0     64.0M   0% /dev/shm
/dev/vda1                38.7G      4.1G     34.6G  11% /var/log/mypath
tmpfs                     7.8G     12.0K      7.8G   0% /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
tmpfs                     7.8G         0      7.8G   0% /proc/acpi
tmpfs                    64.0M         0     64.0M   0% /proc/kcore
tmpfs                    64.0M         0     64.0M   0% /proc/keys
tmpfs                    64.0M         0     64.0M   0% /proc/timer_list
tmpfs                    64.0M         0     64.0M   0% /proc/timer_stats
tmpfs                    64.0M         0     64.0M   0% /proc/sched_debug
tmpfs                     7.8G         0      7.8G   0% /proc/scsi
tmpfs                     7.8G         0      7.8G   0% /sys/firmware

# cd /var/log/mypath/

/var/log/mypath # date >> file_in_container1.txt
/var/log/mypath # date >> file_in_container1.txt

/var/log/mypath # cat file_in_container1.txt
Tue Feb  4 10:25:32 UTC 2020
Tue Feb  4 10:25:34 UTC 2020
```

Now **connect tow second container in the deployment** and it should see the file from first as below

```
$ kubectl exec -it multipod-5758475c69-fkl57 -c busy2 /bin/sh

/ # cd /var/log/mypath/
/var/log/mypath # ls
date                     file_in_container1.txt   

/var/log/mypath # cat file_in_container1.txt
Tue Feb  4 10:25:32 UTC 2020
Tue Feb  4 10:25:34 UTC 2020
```

Now when we **scale this deployment** and create more replica (**since i have used hostPath not nfs i will have to make sure all replica pod run on same node**)

```
$ kubectl scale deployment --replicas=2 multipod
deployment.apps/multipod scaled

$ kubectl get all -o wide
NAME                            READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP               NODE                NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
pod/multipod-5758475c69-7xl9j   2/2     Running   0          47s   192.168.58.112   k8s-node02-calico   <none>           <none>
pod/multipod-5758475c69-fkl57   2/2     Running   0          21m   192.168.58.111   k8s-node02-calico   <none>           <none>

NAME                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE   SELECTOR
service/kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1    <none>        443/TCP   38h   <none>

NAME                       READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE   CONTAINERS    IMAGES            SELECTOR
deployment.apps/multipod   2/2     2            2           21m   busy1,busy2   busybox,busybox   app=multipod

NAME                                  DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE   CONTAINERS    IMAGES            SELECTOR
replicaset.apps/multipod-5758475c69   2         2         2       21m   busy1,busy2   busybox,busybox   app=multipod,pod-template-hash=5758475c69
```

**New replica is also able to read the files as expected**.

```
$ kubectl exec -it multipod-5758475c69-7xl9j /bin/sh
Defaulting container name to busy1.
Use 'kubectl describe pod/multipod-5758475c69-7xl9j -n default' to see all of the containers in this pod.

/ # cd /var/log/mypath/
/var/log/mypath # ls
file_in_container1.txt

/var/log/mypath # cat file_in_container1.txt
Tue Feb  4 10:25:32 UTC 2020
Tue Feb  4 10:25:34 UTC 2020
/var/log/mypath #
```

Comment: Even after changing access mode to the ReadWriteMany it's not giving me same database in pod2 as I given and set the DB in the pod1.

Comment: can you update output for `$ kubectl get pv` and `$ kubectl get pvc` in your question.

Comment: Please also share `$ kubectl describe pv <your-pv-name>` and `$ kubectl describe pvc <your-pvc-name>` .. also what path your are writing to and reading from ?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaTqT.png .....      mountPath: /data

Comment: as i see from details in above screenshots that you are using hostPath as your PV, So if you go back to my example above you should ensure all replica(pod run on same node) .. because hostPath on each node will be different and will have different data.

Comment: looks fine to me

Comment: also are you ensuring that you create the required path on your worker node ?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7q1HR.png  @DT here can't getting same data in another pod

Comment: share output for `$ kubectl get all -o wide` as well

Comment: I will recommend you to review how you are creating hostpath on your minikube and hostpath read write settings